# javacc skip comments but need to keep useful comments

Tags: java, javacc

I need to use javaCC to parse a data file like:

> //This is comment to skip
>
> //This is also comment to skip
>
> //student Table
>
> Begin:
>
> header:(  1 //name
>           2 //age ) {   "John"  21 } {  "Jack"  "22" }
>
> #End
>
> //The following is teacher table, this line is also comment to skip
>
> //Teacher Table
>
> Begin:
>
> header:(  1 //name
>           2 //age   3 //class ) {   "Eric"  31  "English" } {   "Jasph"     "32"    "History" }
>
> #End

Here I need to fetch data from "student" and "teacher" tables, there are also some other tables formatted like above. Data exported from "student" table is:

```
Table Name: student

name age

John 21

Jack 22
```

That is I need to skip comments like: `"//This is also comment to skip"`, but need to keep the tokens like: `"//student Table"`, `"//Teacher Table"`, `"//name"`, `"//age"` etc. How to write such SKIP expression? Thanks.

Comment: Change the format of your data. You're making your life so much harder by allowing data to "look" like a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly late, but you might be looking at it wrong.

Surely in your case, // isn't really a comment, it is part of the syntax you are parsing. It just happens that sometimes the bit following // is irrelevant.

I would parse the comments and decide which ones to discard in your Java code.